# Interface.GetMethods() includes get and set statements in c#

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

When I call `inter.GetMethods()`, it gives me a list of methods *including* all the get and set statements. How can I check whether each item (in a `foreach`) is a get or set statement.

```
foreach (MethodInfo meth in inter.GetMethods()) Console.WriteLine(meth.Name);
```

Comment: Is it not possible to use the [`GetMethods(*overload*)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d848zkb.aspx) that takes `BindingFlags` and exclude the Properties from the start?

Comment: There is my code. Can you show me how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly the most elegant, but it works:

```
List<MethodInfo> propertyGetterSetters = new List<MethodInfo>();
foreach(PropertyInfo prop in typeof(MyType).GetProperties())
{
    var getter = prop.GetGetMethod();
    var setter = prop.GetSetMethod();

    if (getter != null)
        propertyGetterSetters.Add(getter);

    if (setter != null)
        propertyGetterSetters.Add(setter);
}


List<MethodInfo> nonPropertyMethods = typeof(MyType).GetMethods().Except(propertyGetterSetters).ToList();
```

You could also use `MethodInfo.IsSpecialName`, but that can also pick up on other special cases other than just properties, but if you have a simple class that you can test and see that it works, you can use it instead. I wouldn't recommend it; I'd rather just use a utility method like I have above:

`var nonPropertyMethods = typeof(MyType).GetMethods().Where(m => !m.IsSpecialName);`

Comment: Thanks, this is good. What I ended up doing was checking whether they have `get_` or `set_` at the start of their name. I know that wouldn't work blind.

Comment: @ArlenBeiler I wouldn't do that; seems too brittle. On the one hand, you could legitimately prefix a non-property method with "get_....". On the other hand, and I may be wrong on this, the compiled name might not be guaranteed for different implementations of .NET/mono, or for future versions. But if it works for you, go for it!